# When running rdoc the folders 'images' and 'js' are not copied to the doc dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rdoc

I am running rdoc 2.5.9 and when I generate rdoc with the default 'Darkfish' template just by running:

```
rdoc app README
```

in my rails root folder. All the files are generated but the 'images' and 'js' folder is missing in the doc directory. So I need to copy them manualy.

I have the following versions:

```
gem 1.3.7
ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.8
rvm 0.1.41
```

Do I need to specify more command-line arguments to get those folders copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug.  More information about it [here](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=2472&aid=26923&group_id=627).

Comment: tnx! I read it, but I thought it would be resolved by now... it has status closed!